# Is it possible to create a table and add indexes in the same script

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

When creating a table using the access user interface you are able to create a table that has indexed fields that allow duplicates but when you are creating SQL scripts to create the table you use the "Unique" key word to add indexes but that doesn't allow duplicates on the field.
Below is the script to create the table with indexes.

```
CREATE TABLE ASSIGNMENT
(
    ASSIGNMENT_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    TASK_ID INTEGER UNIQUE, 
    EMPLOYEE_ID INTEGER UNIQUE,
    ASSIGNMENT_START_DATE DATETIME,
    ASSIGNMENT_END_DATE DATETIME,
    SKILL_ID INTEGER UNIQUE
);
```

This is the result showing EMPLOYEE_ID [image: Showing what the script does]

And here is how I want the EMPLOYEE_ID to show [image]

I have tried to just use the word Index but the script wont run and has issues saying "Syntax Error"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that what you describe cannot be done in a single CREATE TABLE statement. The DDL for Access SQL allows us to specify `PRIMARY KEY` and `UNIQUE` *Constraints* as properties of columns we include in our CREATE TABLE statements, but it does not seem to offer the same convenience if we simply want that column to be *Indexed* (allowing duplicates).

So, you'll probably just have to do it in two steps:

```sql
CREATE TABLE ASSIGNMENT
(
    ASSIGNMENT_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    TASK_ID INTEGER UNIQUE, 
    EMPLOYEE_ID INTEGER,
    ASSIGNMENT_START_DATE DATETIME,
    ASSIGNMENT_END_DATE DATETIME,
    SKILL_ID INTEGER UNIQUE
)
```

... followed immediately by ...

```sql
CREATE INDEX idxEMPLOYEE_ID ON ASSIGNMENT (EMPLOYEE_ID)
```